# CWL: Creating input yaml - issue with ruamel comments.py

Tags: workflow, ruamel.yaml

I am using cwltool version 3.0.20201203173111 that came with `pip install cwl-runner`. This might be issue with ruamel or with my workflow but here is run command and traceback:

`cwltool --make-template --debug tumor_only_exome.cwl > hiv_input.yml`

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/coyote/anaconda3/envs/cwl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cwltool/main.py", line 991, in main
    make_template(tool)
  File "/home/coyote/anaconda3/envs/cwl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cwltool/main.py", line 744, in make_template
    generate_input_template(tool),
  File "/home/coyote/anaconda3/envs/cwl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cwltool/main.py", line 301, in generate_input_template
    template.insert(0, name, value, comment)
  File "/home/coyote/anaconda3/envs/cwl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/comments.py", line 722, in insert
    self.yaml_add_eol_comment(comment, key=key)
  File "/home/coyote/anaconda3/envs/cwl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/comments.py", line 295, in yaml_add_eol_comment
    if comment[0] != '#':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: That is not an issue with `ruamel.yaml`.  If someone is not provided a comment when calling `yaml_add_eol_comment`, they should not be calling the method in the first place.

Comment: The recommended extension for YAML files has been .yaml since Sep 2006. There are also YML files (a dialect of XML), but `ruamel.yaml` cannot handle those.

Comment: Thanks.  I submitted an issue to cwltool who called it from their main caller so i'll see what they say.  It's supposed to give lines like `num2: 0  # type "int"` but that is for simple cwl workflow that worked and not mine

Comment: If they can't fix this, you can of course check in the comment.py that an empty comment is passed in and do nothing. Insert `if not comment: return` before line 295 if you want to do that.